# Insert Data from Staging to Target table based on events

Tags: triggers, azure-functions, azure-sql-database

This may have been asked before but I couldn't find enough information on this.

So i have a process that will be writing data to my staging table (Table A). I want to Validate Table A data with a master table (Table B) and then write all or subset of the Table A data to my target Table (Table C).

In the end, the data will move from Table A to C. Any records that will fall off from Table A, needs to be written to Table D.

I am looking do this process as soon as data is inserted in Table A. I was hoping to use an azure function but it seems Azure Functions don't support triggers with SQL Databases (yet). Any suggestions on how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server has its own triggers so you don’t need Azure Functions or other third-party tools. SQL triggers can detect inserts, updates, and deletes to execute any tsql commands you desire.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15